# Problems with RealmDB objects in React Native with Reactotron

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I'm having trouble with RealmDB objects in a React Native project, every query I do the RealmDB returns array of empty objects `{}` in reactotron and if I try to use rest/spread operator. However, when I access
attribute by attribute works. Someone had the same issue and managed to solve?
P.S: I already linked realm and reactotron in the project

Images about what I described

Reactotron: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhN1D.png
Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsNwk.png

An example of a piece of code where I try to discover the problem:

```
async getAllMov(){
    try{
        const realm = await getRealm();
        const listaMov = realm.objects(MovSchema.schema.name);

        console.tron.log(listaMov[4]);

        const d = {...listaMov[4]};

        console.tron.log(d);

        let dados = {
            movID: listaMov[4].movID,
            titulo: listaMov[4].titulo,
            descricao: listaMov[4].descricao,
            valor: listaMov[4].valor,
            tipo: listaMov[4].tipo
        }; 

        console.tron.log(dados);


    }catch(e){
        console.tron.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here, have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and i give up because i had a problem with Realm and 
and I had to remove it from the project.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, I hope that helps you also:

```
export default function getRealmObjects = async (schemaName) => {

        const realm = await getRealm();

        var objects = realm.objects(schemaName);

        //this is because realm put some obstacles when you try to modify it's objects, the solution found was to clone the results before return
        let result = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

            let item = {};
            for (const key in objects[i]) {
                item[key] = objects[i][key];
            }

            result.push(item)
        }

        return result?.length > 0 ? result : [];
}
```

Basically you cannot modify realm objects, so you have to clone it before use.

Comment: When i used  i did the same ( variable dados which i used as an example) just to see the info, but i don't accept this as a solution because its a "trick"  and i'm not modifying the object. So i don't understand why it happens.

Comment: Well I use this as a "getter" function, and what the function returns can be perfectly modified.